# input shape of keras Sequential model

Tags: keras, mse, sgd

i am new to neural networks using keras,
i have the following train samples input shape **(150528, 1235)** and output shape is **(154457, 1235)** where **1235** is the training examples,
how to put the input shape, i tried below but gave me a

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 150528
  y sizes: 154457
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(150528,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(154457)
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])
model.fit(im_features, amp_vo_features, batch_size=10, epochs=30, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure that your `x` and `y` values have the same row dimension. This can be done using [`numpy.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html).

```
import numpy as np

t = np.random.rand(150528, 1235)
np.transpose(t).shape # (1235, 150528)
np.swapaxes(t, 0, 1).shape # (1235, 150528)
```

This should give the shapes of `(1235, 150528)` for `x` and `(1235, 154457)` for `y`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it worked out fine now